# How to fix this alignment issue with emojis

Tags: qiskit, python

When I include emojis as a parameter, the printout is shifted, but works fine without emojis if, say, θ or ψ is used.

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit import Parameter, ParameterVector

parameter_0 = Parameter('')
parameter_1 = Parameter('')
parameter_2 = Parameter('')
parameter_3 = Parameter('θ')

circuit = QuantumCircuit(1)
circuit.ry(theta = parameter_0, qubit = 0)
circuit.rx(theta = parameter_1, qubit = 0) 
circuit.rz(phi   = parameter_2, qubit = 0) 
circuit.ry(theta = parameter_3,qubit = 0)

circuit.draw()
```

[image]

Comment: That question made me smile enough that I hope it doesn't get closed

Comment: What specifically is the alignment issue?  What is happening vice what do you expect to happen?

Comment: The output circuit image with emojis is shifted and misaligned.

Comment: I would assume that the problem is the emoji in question have a terminal cell width of 2, rather than 1, and `circuit.draw()` doesn't compensate for wide characters. θ and ψ have a width of 1 terminal cell, while ,  and  have a width of 2 terminal cells, i.e. are treated as wide characters, like Han ideographs. No one has built what I would consider to be a modern terminal yet, anachronisms  such as wide characters are deeply embedded in terminal/console solutions.

You may have to try it using another drawing format, not sure if the draw method has wide character support.

Comment: Thank you  for the clarification...cheers